# Running python paypal payment gateway in php

Tags: javascript, php, python

So I have this python script which I wish to call using php.

I have trying using exec & ajax to implement however I have had no luck

I am using XAMMP has an internal server & dreamweaver to code

Python (.py)

```
    from uvm.settings_reader import get_nodeid_settings
from mod_python import apache
from mod_python import util
from mod_python import Session
from uvm import Uvm
import cgi
import simplejson as json
from datetime import datetime
import urllib
import urllib2
import random
import time


# PayPal sandbox URL.This URL's IP address along with www.paypalobjects.com corresponding IP address must be added into Captive Portal, Passed Hosts, Pass Listed Server Addresses
PAYPAL_URL="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com"

#the button should be created by the user which receives the payment  The URL of this page must be set in the button to receive notifications
#For the cancelCheckot notification: http://[Untangle box IP]/capture/custom_[n]/custom.py/cancelCheckout
#For the finish checkount notification: http://[Untangle box IP]/capture/custom_[n]/custom.py/finishCheckout
BUTTON_ID="VMSV6QK9LA3HS"

# The user which receives the payments must set Auto Return to Website Payments to On
# and set the return URL similar to the finish checkout notification: http://[Untangle box IP]/capture/custom_[n]/custom.py/finishCheckout
# Payment Data Transfer must be set to On and the generated identity token must be used below

PDT_IDENTITY_TOKEN='m_f6twlH32gWmylq65npQkDvKNDCdhX6PjfGBycZu5f0ynCfjQrN4iSLNLG'

# General Note: While this custom page is active be aware that admin actions in the WebUI on Local Directory can overwrite
# new users created by this page if those users are created while the admin is performing actions in the WebUI

def buyNowButton( url, buttonid):
    retVal ='<form action="%s/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">' % url
    retVal +='<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">'
    retVal +='<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="%s">' % buttonid
    retVal +='<input type="image" src="%s/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">' % url
    retVal +='<img alt="" border="0" src="%s/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">' % url
    retVal +='</form>'
    return retVal

def loginForm(appid, host, uri, user=None, password=None):
    page = "<FORM AUTOCOMPLETE='OFF' METHOD='POST' ACTION='/capture/handler.py/custom_handler?appid=" + appid + "'>"
    page += "<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=8>"
    if not user:
        page += "<TR><TD>Username</TD><TD><INPUT WIDTH=80 TYPE='text' NAME='username' ID='username'></INPUT></TD></TR>"
    else:
        page += "<TR><TD>Username</TD><TD><INPUT WIDTH=80 TYPE='text' NAME='username' ID='username' value='%s'></INPUT></TD></TR>" % user
    if not password:
        page += "<TR><TD>Password</TD><TD><INPUT WIDTH=80 TYPE='password' NAME='pwd' ID='pwd'></INPUT></TD></TR>"
    else:
        page += "<TR><TD>Password</TD><TD><INPUT WIDTH=80 TYPE='password' NAME='pwd' ID='pwd' value='%s'></INPUT></TD></TR>" % password
    page += "</TABLE>"
    page += "<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='host' ID='host' VALUE='" + host + "'></INPUT>"
    page += "<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='uri' ID='uri' VALUE='" + uri + "'></INPUT>"
    page += "<P><BUTTON TYPE='submit' NAME='submit' ID='submit' TITLE='Login' value='Login'>Login</BUTTON></P>"
    page += "</FORM>"
    return page




# When you include a custom.py file in your custom captive portal zip file
# you get full control over the capture and authentication process.

# When the captive portal intercepts traffic and a capture page needs to
# be displayed, our main handler will call your index function and will
# pass you a bunch of parameters you can use to build your custom page:
#
# req - this is the apache request object
# rawpath - this is the full path to where the custom files are stored
#   and it will include the trailing backslash
#   e.g.: /usr/share/untangle/web/capture/custom_6/
# webpath - this is the relative path from which images and other
#   linked content can be specified and includes trailing backslash
#   e.g.: /capture/custom_6/
# appid - each instance of captive portal is assigned a unique appid
#   value that you MUST include as a parameter to the custom_handler
#   so the mod_python scripts know which instance to work with
#   e.g.: 6
# host - this is the host from the original HTTP request that resulted
#   in the captive page display
#   e.g.: www.yahoo.com
# uri - this is the path from the original HTTP request that resulted
#   in the captive page display
#   e.g.: /some/page/or/something/content.html
#
# In our example below we create a simple page with a form where the hotel
# guest can enter their name and room number.  Note that the POST handler
# is set to the parent captive portal handler, and we pass the appid so it
# knows which instance of captive portal is calling.  Our example doesn't
# need the rawpath but we do use the webpath to include a spiffy image
# and page icon.  We hide the original host and uri in the form so we can
# redirect the user to their original destination after authentication.\

def index(req,rawpath,webpath,appid,host,uri):
    session = Session.Session(req)
    if session.is_new():
        session['rawpath']=rawpath
        session['webpath']=webpath
        session['appid']=appid
        session['host']=host
        session['uri']=uri
        session.save()
    page = "<HTML><HEAD>"
    page += "<META http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />"
    page += "<body>"
    page += "<h2>Login or buy 1 Day pass<h2>"
    page += loginForm(appid,host,uri)
    page += "<br/><br/>"
    page += buyNowButton(PAYPAL_URL, BUTTON_ID)
    page += "<body>"
    page += "</html>"
    req.content_type = "text/html"
    req.write(page)


def cancelCheckout(req):
    session = Session.Session(req)
    if not session.is_new():
        index(req,session['rawpath'],session['webpath'],session['appid'],session['host'],session['uri'])
    else:
        page = "<html><body><H1>Cancel checkout </H1></body></html>"
        req.content_type = "text/html"
        req.write(page)

def generatePassword(length):
    return ''.join(map(lambda x:random.choice('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVXYZ0123456789'), range(length)))

def finishCheckout(req):
    page = "<html><body><H1>Checkout finished</H1></body></html>"
    params = util.FieldStorage(req)
    tx=params.get("tx","")
    if len(tx) > 0:
        url = "%s/cgi-bin/webscr" % PAYPAL_URL
        data = urllib.urlencode({'tx': tx,'at':PDT_IDENTITY_TOKEN,'cmd':'_notify-synch'})
        results = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
        html = results.read()
        page +='<br/>';
        if html.find('SUCCESS') != -1:
            values = html.split('\n')
            for value in values:
                if value.find('payer_email') != -1:
                    parts = value.split('=')
                    email = parts[len(parts)-1]
                    email = urllib.unquote(email).decode('utf8')
                    context = Uvm().getUvmContext()
                    if not context:
                        raise Exception("The uvm context could not be obtained")
                    localDirectory = context.localDirectory()
                    if not localDirectory:
                        raise Exception("The uvm node manager could not locate the local directory instance")
                    pwd = generatePassword(6)
                    userToRegister={"email": "%s"%email, "firstName":"", "lastName":"", "password":"%s"%pwd, "username":"%s"%email, "expirationTime":int((time.time() + 86400)*1000), "javaClass":"com.untangle.uvm.LocalDirectoryUser"}
                    if not localDirectory.userExists(userToRegister):
                        localDirectory.addUser(userToRegister)
                        page += "<b>Login credentials</b> <br/><br/>"
                        page += "Username:<b>%s</b><br/>" % email
                        page += "Password:<b>%s</b><br/><br/>" % pwd
                        page += "Save the credentials and press the login button below to access the Internet<br/><br/>"
                    else:
                        updatedUser={"email": "%s"%email, "username":"%s"%email, "expirationTime":int((time.time() + 86400)*1000), "javaClass":"com.untangle.uvm.LocalDirectoryUser"}
                        localDirectory.updateUser(updatedUser)

                    session = Session.Session(req)
                    try:
                        page += loginForm(session['appid'],session['host'],session['uri'], email, pwd)
                    except KeyError:
                        pass
        else:
            page += html
    req.content_type = "text/html"
    req.write(page)



# When our parent post handler gets the form defined above, it will call
# your handler function passing many of the same arguments described above.
def handler(req,rawpath,webpath,appid, loginMap={}):

    # get the network address of the client
    address = req.get_remote_host(apache.REMOTE_NOLOOKUP,None)

    # grab the form fields from the post data
    uname=req.form['username'].value
    pwd = req.form['pwd'].value
    host = req.form['host'].value
    uri = req.form['uri'].value

    # first we get the uvm context
    context = Uvm().getUvmContext()
    if not context:
        raise Exception("The uvm context could not be obtained")

    # now we use the uvm context to get the captive portal node instance
    # note that we pass the appid so we get a reference to the correct instance
    capture = context.nodeManager().node(long(appid))
    if not capture:
        raise Exception("The uvm node manager could not locate the capture node instance")

    # we also want the node settings so we can check for a custom redirect target
    settings = get_nodeid_settings(long(appid))
    if (settings == None):
        raise Exception("Unable to load capture node settings")

    captureAuth = capture.userAuthenticate(address, uname, pwd)

    # if a redirect URL is configured we send the user to that location
    if (len(settings['redirectUrl']) != 0) and (settings['redirectUrl'].isspace() == False):
        target = str(settings['redirectUrl'])
    # no redirect URL is configured so send the user to the originally requested page
    else:
        # if the host or uri are empty we just return a simple success page
        if ((host == 'Empty') or (uri == 'Empty')):
            page = "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Login Success</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Login Success</H1></BODY></HTML>"
            return(page)
        else:
            target = str("http://" + host + uri)

    util.redirect(req, target)
```

When I run this script in chrome, it is unable to process it & only shows the text

Comment: Not sure why you gave us the Python script. Now we have no idea how you're calling this script or what the error.log from your webserver says the problem is. Could you correct this? Also, try to include a - minimal working example - **WITHOUT YOUR IDENTITY TOKEN**

Comment: This code works by using the Captive Portal portal of the untangle gateway

When uploaded to the untangle gateway, it works perfectlly. I would like to simply call it in php

Comment: And the portal is calling a PHP script that execute the Python script... how?

Comment: The portal simply runs the script and displays the script

http://i.imgur.com/kU3jv92.jpg

Comment: Quote: `I have this python script which I wish to call using php`. **how** does PHP call the script? I'm not talking about some windows/osx solution to automatically pop up a web-page for users on a wifi (or ethernet).. I'm talking about how you programatically are trying to do what you're doing - and why that doesn't work.

Comment: So let me explain how I picture this in my head. 

The python script works once it is uploaded to the gateway, as the page is quite plain I would like to embed it with php inside an .html file .  

atm when someone connects to the wifi, this is displayed 
http://i.imgur.com/kU3jv92.jpg , 

i am wondering if it is possible to display this script in a php section within an html . 

Thanks for the help btw :)

Comment: So.. You're asking if it's possible - not why it's not working? If that's the case - the answer is Yes.. It's possible. Just do `exec()` on the script from PHP.